# Simple way to create a tunnel from one local port to another?

Tags: networking, tcp, tunneling, port-forwarding

I have a development server, which is only accessible from 127.0.0.1:8000, not 192.168.1.x:8000. As a quick hack, is there a way to set up something to listen on another port (say, 8001) so that from the local network I could connect 192.168.1.x:8001 and it would tunnel the traffic between the client and 127.0.0.1:8000?

Comment: [netcat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) can do this.

Comment: Is there anything that can be run on an Android device? Or a limitation of Android that prevents such a solution?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Using ssh is the easiest solution.

> ssh -g -L 8001:localhost:8000 -f -N user@remote-server.com

This forwards the local port 8001 on your workstation to the localhost address on remote-server.com port 8000.
`-g` means allow other clients on my network to connect to port 8001 on my workstation.  Otherwise only local clients on your workstation can connect to the forwarded port.
`-N` means all I am doing is forwarding ports, don't start a shell.
`-f` means fork into background after a successful SSH connection and log-in.
Port 8001 will stay open for many connections, until ssh dies or is killed.  If you happen to be on Windows, the excellent SSH client PuTTY can do this as well.  Use 8001 as the local port and localhost:8000 and the destination and add a local port forwarding in settings.  You can add it after a successful connect with PuTTY.

Comment: What does the `user@remote-server.com` do? It's definitely unneeded for port forwarding, however ssh mandates having this argument, more over, it tries to connect there. And upon setting this pesky option to hostname it outputs `…port 22: Connection refused` *(no, I didn't use the 22 port)*. Unless I'm missing something, the command plainly doesn't work.

Comment: @Hi-Angel `user@remote-server.com` is just an example and you should not take it literally. You have to replace this with a name of computer you want to connect to and your username on this computer. This information is needed to establish ssh connection. Only after ssh connection is established ports can be forwarded through this connection.

Comment: If you want the port to be available from boot then see "autossh" in a systemd service using the above method - https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/

Comment: I also get "connection refused". And I still don't understand why the user@remote-server.com argument is needed when there is no SSH connection involved (according to -N). Should just forward packets.

Comment: @AlexanderTaylor `-N` does not mean there is no SSH connection. It simply means `do not execute a remote command` (see the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)). The `<user>@<host>` argument is necessary, because this _does_ open an SSH connection to `<host>` (which for OP's case would be `localhost`), and forwards the desired port _through_ that SSH tunnel. It is one solution for OP's problem, but not the simplest. To forward to localhost without using ssh, you can use `socat` or `netcat` as in StephaneChazelas and not-a-user 's answers

Comment: Worked for, just needs some explanation.
1. `port 22: Connection refused` mean you need to enable Remote Login on your mac
2. Since the question is about local ports, use localhost instead of `user@remote-server.com`

Answer (score 193):

With `socat` on the server:

```
socat tcp-listen:8001,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:8000
```

By default, `socat` will listen on TCP port 8001 on any IPv4 or IPv6 address (if supported) on the machine. You can restrict it to IPv4/6 by replacing `tcp-listen` with `tcp4-listen` or `tcp6-listen`, or to a specific local address by adding a `,bind=that-address`.

Same for the connecting socket you're proxying to, you can use any address in place of `localhost`, and replace `tcp` with `tcp4` or `tcp6` if you want to restrict the address resolution to IPv4 or IPv6 addresses.

Note that for the server listening on port 8000, the connection will appear as coming from the proxy (in the case of `localhost`, that will be `localhost`), not the original client. You'd need to use [DNAT approaches](/a/285854) (but which requires superuser privileges) for the server to be able to tell who's the client.

Comment: Thanks, this is great since you do not have to have a local ssh server running.

Comment: Can I use the same port but different address?

Comment: @amos, see edit.

Comment: Would it also be possible to forward traffic only from specific IPs?

Comment: @Phate, see [Tell socat to listen to connections from a single IP address](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/210741) (and the `range` and `tcpwrap` options in the `socat` man page).

Comment: this solution better than `nc.traditional` solution below, this one didn't disconnect after a few connections

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, even for port 80 which was the problem for me with some of the other suggestions

Comment: Trying to use it for local port forwarding, works for localhost but not for other clients in the same subnet. Is there any way to make it accept external connections as well?

Answer (score 70):

Using the traditional `nc` is the easiest solution:

```
nc -l -p 8001 -c "nc 127.0.0.1 8000"
```

This version of `nc` is in the `netcat-traditional` package on Ubuntu. (You have to `update-alternatives` or call it `nc.traditional`.)

Note that in contrast to ssh this is not encrypted. Keep that in mind if you use it outside one host.

Comment: anyone know the equivalent on `netcat-openbsd`?

Comment: Analog for `netcat` version that is included in `busybox`: `nc -v -lk -p 8001 -e /usr/bin/nc 127.0.0.1 8000`. ([Description of params](https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#nc))

Comment: Working, but the `nc` command ends after the first remote connection. Add `-k` if you need to keep it running.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `nc: cannot use -p and -l` on CentOS 6.4. Is there a work around?

Comment: I prefer this solution over the ssh one because it makes it easier to use as root, when one needs to locally forward a privileged port.

Comment: Works great, even on Windows, thanks!

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez Hi! Yoy wrote: "Add -k if you need to keep it running". Excuse me, can you give a full example of command? I try "nc -l -k -p 5555 <fifo | nc 127.0.0.1 8000 >fifo", and this finish just like without a -k key

Comment: What's the OS X equivalent?

Answer (score 36):

OpenBSD netcat is available by default on Linux and also on OS X.

OSX:

```
mkfifo a
mkfifo b
nc 127.0.0.1 8000 < b > a &
nc -l 8001 < a > b &
```

Linux:

```
mkfifo backpipe
nc -l 12345 0<backpipe | nc www.google.com 80 1>backpipe
```

An alternative that works on OS X bash is to use a [bidirectional pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs). It may work on other Unixes:

```
nc 127.0.0.1 8000 <&1 | nc -l 8001 >&0
```

Comment: I didn't notice at first that you were using openbsd netcat. This is better than having to install another netcat from an Ubuntu package.

Comment: OpenBSD example failed on Ubuntu 15.04.  With the shell redirects, netcat fails to open the port for listening as seen by `ss -tan` or `netstat -tan`.

Comment: ⁺¹. FTR: the alternative way works on Ubuntu

Comment: I don't understand your solution. Can you explain it?

Comment: @trismegistos In these examples the netcat listener and client redirect input into some shared files (mkfifo pipes..first in first out), and use those shared files as their source/destination of input/output, effectively creating a tunnel. Usually client/listener are used, but some techniques use client+client/listener+listener- https://wiki.securityweekly.com/Episode195#A_Traditional_Client-to-Listener_Netcat_Relay    __and__ https://www.slideshare.net/amiable_indian/secrets-of-top-pentesters are must reads.

Comment: Any way to make it handle multiple connections?

Answer (score 6):

Quoting a [David Spillett](https://serverfault.com/users/5221/david-spillett)'s [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/18002/144005) on ServerFault, replacing the missing link with a working repo:

> rinetd should do the job, and a Windows binary for it can be had from https://github.com/samhocevar/rinetd (for anyone looking for the same thing under Linux, rinetd is in the standard repositories of just about every distro so can be installed with "apt-get install rinetd" or "yum install rinetd" or similar)

It is a simple binary that takes a configuration file in the format

`bindaddress bindport connectaddress connectport`

For example:

`192.168.1.1 8001 127.0.0.1 8000`

or

`0.0.0.0 8001 127.0.0.1 8000`

if you want to bind the incoming port to all the interfaces.

Comment: Broken link now points at https://github.com/boutell/rinetd (archived), which then hints towards https://github.com/samhocevar/rinetd. [HTML documentation is available](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/samhocevar/rinetd/blob/main/index.html).

Comment: @HelderMagalhães thanks, repo fixed. Better late than never :)

Answer (score 4):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport <origin-port> -j REDIRECT --to-port <destination-port>

service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Comment: Upon trying to connect to `dport`, as in `nc -v localhost 2345`, I'm getting `Connection refused`. I'm not very good in iptables, but I guess the dport has to have a listening app.

Comment: What if origin-port is on different interface than destination port?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Mark A.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/42236/mark-a)'s answer, I had to make a small tweak to get it to work for my Mac (at least on macOS Mojave Version 10.14.4)

```
mkfifo a
mkfifo b
nc 127.0.0.1 8000 < b > a &
nc -l 8001 < a > b &
printf "" > a
```

That printf statement seems to be crucial. Otherwise the netcat command to connect to port 8000 will never actually try to connect, and the netcat command to listen on port 8001 will never actually listen on port 8001. Without the printf, every time I would try to connect to port 8001 I would get connection refused.

My assumption is that netcat must somehow block on stdin (maybe it's trying to read it for some reason) before actually doing any Socket operations. As such, without the printf statement writing to fifo a, the netcat command will never start listening on port 8001.

Note: I would have left an answer on Mark's post, but I don't have reputation yet.

Comment: This is the only answer that sort of worked for me.  With two problems: 1) It only listens on the first request, even if I add `-k`.  2) It's as slow as molasses.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new way to tunnel two udp ports on server:
https://github.com/9crk/udpeer

`udpeer 8001 8002`

To test:

```
nc -u xxxx.com 8001
nc -u xxxx.com 8002
```