# How to make bidirectional pipe between two programs?

Tags: shell, pipe

Everyone knows how to make unidirectional pipe between two programs (bind `stdout` of first one and `stdin` of second one): `first | second`.

But how to make bidirectional pipe, i.e. cross-bind `stdin` and `stdout` of two programs? Is there easy way to do it in a shell?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If pipes on your system are bidirectional (as they are on Solaris 11 and some BSDs at least, but not Linux):

```
cmd1 <&1 | cmd2 >&0
```

Beware of deadlocks though.

Also note that some versions of ksh93 on some systems implement pipes (`|`) using a *socket pair*. socket pairs are bidirectional, but ksh93 explicitly shuts down the reverse direction, so the command above wouldn't work with those ksh93s even on systems where pipes (as created by the `pipe(2)` system call) are bidirectional.

Comment: does anyone know whether this works on linux too? (using archlinux here)

Comment: @heinrich5991 - [*"On some systems (but not Linux), pipes are bidirectional*"](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

Answer (score 50):

Well, its fairly "easy" with named pipes (`mkfifo`). I put easy in quotes because unless the programs are designed for this, deadlock is likely.

```shell
mkfifo fifo0 fifo1
( prog1 > fifo0 < fifo1 ) &
( prog2 > fifo1 < fifo0 ) &
( exec 30<fifo0 31<fifo1 )      # write can't open until there is a reader
                                # and vice versa if we did it the other way
```

Now, there is normally buffering involved in writing stdout. So, for example, if both programs were:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;
say 1;
print while (<>);
```

you'd expect a infinite loop. But instead, both would deadlock; you would need to add `$| = 1` (or equivalent) to turn off output buffering. The deadlock is caused because *both* programs are waiting for something on stdin, but they're not seeing it because its sitting in the stdout buffer of the other program, and hasn't yet been written to the pipe.

**Update**: incorporating suggestions from Stéphane Charzelas and Joost:

```shell
mkfifo fifo0 fifo1
prog1 > fifo0 < fifo1 &
prog2 < fifo0 > fifo1
```

does the same, is shorter, and more portable.

Comment: One named pipe is sufficient: `prog1 < fifo | prog2 > fifo`.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov that's true, you can substitute an anonymous pipe for one of the named ones. But I like the symmetry :-P

Comment: @Andrey Vihrov: Perfect! But how can also I see communication of this programs in a terminal? I.e. I want, prog1 and prog2 also output to calling terminal.

Comment: @user14284: On Linux, you can probably do it with something like `prog1 < fifo | tee /dev/stderr | prog2 | tee /dev/stderr > fifo`.

Comment: If you make it `prog2 < fifo0 > fifo1`, you can avoid your little dance with `exec 30< ...` (which by the way only works with `bash` or `yash` for fds over 10 like that).

Comment: Why would you use subshells here? Is it related to of the `exec` command opening the file descriptors?

Comment: @Joost Hmmm, appears you're correct that there is no need, at least in bash. I was probably worried that since the shell performs the redirects (including opening the pipes), it might block—but at least bash forks before opening the fifos. `dash` seems OK too (but behaves a little differently)

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to do:

```
nc -l -p 8096 -c second &
nc -c first 127.0.0.1 8096 &
```

This begins by opening a listening socket on port 8096, and once a connection is established, spawns program `second` with its `stdin` as the stream output and `stdout` as the stream input.

Then, a second `nc` is launched which connects to the listening port and spawns program `first` with its `stdout` as the stream input and its `stdin` as the stream output.

This is not exactly done using a pipe, but it seems to do what you need.

As this uses the network, this can be done on 2 remote computers.  This is almost the way a web server (`second`) and a web browser (`first`) work.

Comment: And `nc -U` for UNIX domain sockets that only take filesystem address space.

Comment: -c option is not available in Linux. My happiness was a short lived one :-(

Answer (score 12):

You can use [pipexec](https://github.com/flonatel/pipexec):

```
$ pipexec -- '[A' cmd1 ] '[B' cmd2 ] '{A:1>B:0}' '{B:1>A:0}'
```

Answer (score 12):

`bash` version 4 has `coproc` command that allows this done in pure `bash` without named pipes.

From `bash` man page about `coproc` command:

> coproc [NAME] command [redirections]
>
> This creates a coprocess named NAME.
> If NAME is not supplied, the default name is COPROC.

> The standard output of command is connected via a pipe
> to a file descriptor in the executing shell, and that file
> descriptor is assigned to NAME[0].
> The  standard input of command is connected via a pipe to a
> file descriptor in the executing shell, and that file
> descriptor is assigned to NAME[1].

Start with a version easy to understand (but does not work). Start entire pipeline under `coproc` and use extra `cat` for plumbing.

```bsh
coproc {
  cmd1 | cmd2
}
cat <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}
```

Buffering is obviously something that needs to be taken care of. Here plain `cat` will likely break it due to buffering. So use `stdbuf` to disable buffering by `cat`:

```bsh
# this is same as above
coproc {
  cmd1 | cmd2
}
# replace last line from sample above with:
stdbuf -i0 -o0 cat <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}
```

Better still, do away with `cat`. Break up pipeline into two steps, run 1st section under `coproc` and 2nd section to connect with 1st.

```bsh
coproc cmd1
cmd2 <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}
```

This still assumes that `cmd1` and `cmd2` handle buffering correctly to make it work.

Some other shells also can do `coproc` as well.

**That is all the answer above.**

Below is just **some exploration and tests**.

Here example chains three commands only to make it a little more interesting.

```bsh
# start pipeline
coproc {
    cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3
}

# reconnect STDOUT from `cmd3` to STDIN of `cmd1`
stdbuf -i0 -o0 /bin/cat <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}
```

Get rid of `cat` and `stdbuf` and stay with pure bash.
Break it up into two parts, launch the first pipeline under coproc, then launch second part (either a single command or a pipeline), reconnecting it to the first:

```bsh
coproc {
    cmd 1 | cmd2
}
cmd3 <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}
```

**Proof of concept**

File `prog` - a worker program participating in looped IO. Just a dummy prog to consume, tag and re-print lines. It is using subshells to avoid buffering problems maybe overkill, it's not the point here.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Start this prog with only param "1" to produce some output

let c=0
sleep 2

[ "$1" == "1" ] && ( echo start )

while : ; do
  read line
  echo "$1:${c} ${line}" 1>&2
  sleep 2
  ( echo "$1:${c} ${line}" )
  let c++
  [ $c -eq 3 ] && exit
done
```

File `start_io_loop_with_cat` - a demo launcher.
This is a version using `bash`, `cat` and `stdbuf`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# start all 3 commands as one pipeline
coproc {
  ./prog 1 \
  | ./prog 2 \
  | ./prog 3
}

# start cat without buffering to connect IO loop
stdbuf -i0 -o0 /bin/cat <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}
```

File `start_io_loop_pure_bash` - another demo launcher.
This is a version using pure `bash` only.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# start first 2 of 3 commands in the pipeline
coproc {
  ./prog 1 \
  | ./prog 2
}

# start 3rd command connecting IO to 1 and 2 to make the IO loop
./prog 3 <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}
```

Output:

```
> ./start_io_loop_pure_bash
2:0 start
3:0 2:0 start
1:0 3:0 2:0 start
2:1 1:0 3:0 2:0 start
3:1 2:1 1:0 3:0 2:0 start
1:1 3:1 2:1 1:0 3:0 2:0 start
2:2 1:1 3:1 2:1 1:0 3:0 2:0 start
3:2 2:2 1:1 3:1 2:1 1:0 3:0 2:0 start
1:2 3:2 2:2 1:1 3:1 2:1 1:0 3:0 2:0 start
```

That does it.

Answer (score 10):

A convenient building block for writing such bidirectional pipes is something that connects the stdout and stdin of the current process together. Let us call it ioloop. After calling this function, you only need to start a regular pipe:

```
ioloop &&     # stdout -> stdin 
cmd1 | cmd2   # stdin -> cmd1 -> cmd2 -> stdout (-> back to stdin)
```

If you do not want to modify the descriptors of the top-level shell, run this in a subshell:

```
( ioloop && cmd1 | cmd2 )
```

Here is a portable implementation of ioloop using a named pipe:

```
ioloop() {
    FIFO=$(mktemp -u /tmp/ioloop_$$_XXXXXX ) &&
    trap "rm -f $FIFO" EXIT &&
    mkfifo $FIFO &&
    ( : <$FIFO & ) &&    # avoid deadlock on opening pipe
    exec >$FIFO <$FIFO
}
```

The named pipe exists in the filesystem only briefly during ioloop setup. This function is not quite POSIX because mktemp is deprecated (and potentially vulnerable to a race attack).

A linux-specific implementation using /proc/ is possible that does not require a named pipe, but I think this one is more than good enough.

Comment: Interesting function, +1. Could probably use a sentence or 2 added explaining `( : <$FIFO & )` in more detail. Thank you for posting.

Comment: I did a little looking around and came up blank; where can I find out information about the deprecation of `mktemp`?  I use it extensively, and if a newer tool has taken its place, I would like to start using it.

Comment: Alex: the open(2) syscall on a naned pipe is blocking. if you try to "exec <$PIPE >$PIPE" it will get stuck waiting for another process to open the other side. The command ": <$FIFO &" is executed in a subshell in the background and enables the bidirectional redirection to complete successfully.

Comment: DopeGhoti: the mktemp(3) C library function is deprecated. The mktemp(1) utility is not.

Answer (score 7):

There is also

- `dpipe`, the "bi-directional pipe", included in vde2 package, and included in [current distro package management systems](https://packages.debian.org/stable/vde2).

  `dpipe processA = processB`
- [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html), the connect everything-to-everthing tool.

  `socat EXEC:Program1 EXEC:Program2`

As @StéphaneChazelas correctly notes in the comments, above examples are the "base form", he has [nice examples with options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296434/127903) on his answer for a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296432/127903).

Comment: Note that by default, `socat` uses sockets instead of pipes (you can change that with `commtype=pipes`). You may want to add the `nofork` option to avoid an extra socat process shoving data between the pipes/sockets. (thanks for the edit on [my answer](/a/296434) btw)

Answer (score 0):

There are many great answers here. So I just want to add something to easy play around with them. I assume `stderr` is not redirected anywhere. Create two scripts (let say a.sh and b.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "foo" # change to 'bar' in second file

for i in {1..10}; do
  read input
  echo ${input}
  echo ${i} ${0} got: ${input} >&2
done
```

Then when you connect them any good way you should see on the console:

```
1 ./a.sh got: bar
1 ./b.sh got: foo
2 ./a.sh got: foo
2 ./b.sh got: bar
3 ./a.sh got: bar
3 ./b.sh got: foo
4 ./a.sh got: foo
4 ./b.sh got: bar
...
```