# Bypass sshd AllowTCPFowarding=no by installing own forwarder?

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunneling

In the man pages for `sshd_config`, for the `AllowTCPForwarding` option, it states:

> **AllowTcpForwarding**
>
> Specifies whether TCP forwarding is permitted. The default is “yes”.
>   Note that disabling TCP forwarding does not improve security unless
>   users are also denied shell access, as they can always install their
>   own forwarders.

Can someone please elaborate?  I do not understand how someone can install their own forwarder to circumvent TcpForwarding.  Would one have to install a proxy server of sorts and then create a tunnel to the remote proxy server?

Answer (score 5):

Well, SSH forwarding is a proxy server of sorts. It works by accepting the connection on one side, then making a connection on the other side, and then forwarding data between the two.

You could easily do this, too. For example, with netcat:

```
nc -l -p 1234 ⇆ ssh user@remote 'nc remote2 80'
```

where `⇆` represents one of the ways to set up a [bidirectional pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53641/how-to-make-bidirectional-pipe-between-two-programs). That should more or less do it (ignoring any buffering problems).

It isn't as nice as the built-in one, but of course with a little bit of work in your scripting language of choice, it could be.

Answer (score 1):

User with shell access can easily run `sshd` with his/her own configuration (which can e.g. allow TCP forwarding) on an unprivileged port. Hence disabling it for the regular system daemon doesn't make much sense, unless you make a ton of other hardening things.

Comment: That's trivially fixed with `iptables -P INPUT -j DROP` (or equivalent) along with rules to allow the traffic you want, of course. Which should be done already on any system where someone would consider turning off AllowTcpForwarding.

Comment: @derobert Of course, but then you have to set up the firewall (which is the additional hardening I mentioned). You might want to append that in bold to your answer. :)

Comment: @derobert And that's easily countered by using the official SSH but tunnelling into another SSH listening on localhost. (If you firewall localhost connections a lot of things are going to fail.)

Comment: @Gilles I may be misunderstanding, but ssh from localhost to localhost (on the remote machine) isn't going to help much in forwarding a port from your local machine.

Comment: @Gilles If AllowTcpForwarding is disabled though how can the official SSH tunnel into another SSH listening on localhost?  I actually tried that but got the ubiquitous "channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed" error, indicating (I believe) that the official SSH is unable to forward the connection to a local SSH.