# Performing atomic write operations in a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, semaphore

After going through the bash [documentation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/correct-locking-in-shell-scripts) question and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/correct-locking-in-shell-scripts) one it's still not clear to me how can I perform atomic write (append) operations to a file in bash. I have a script that is run in multiple instances and at some point must write data to a file:

```
echo "$RESULT" >> `pwd`/$TEMP_DIR/$OUT_FILE
```

How is it possible to make all write operations from all concurrently running scripts to that file atomic (so that data from one instance doesn't overlap data from another)?

Comment: FYI you don't need `\`pwd\``; you can just use a dot (`.`).  Also you should quote that whole file name since it [includes variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943).

Comment: You may also want to look into the possibility of [using FIFOs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkfifo.html).

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks. I was using `pwd` earlier in the script to notify the user about the current working directory and also write entries in a log file. looking over FIFOs now.

Comment: Actually there is [a better introduction to FIFOs](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/69057/135943) right on this very site; the link I provided a few minutes ago is the POSIX specs for `mkfifo` and not exactly introductory level.

Comment: Whether it's a FIFO or a file, you still run the risk that two instances write at the same time and garble each other's outputs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems you need to use `flock` as in the example from man (http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock)

```
(
flock -x 200

# Put here your commands that must do some writes atomically

) 200>/var/lock/mylockfile
```

And put all your commands that must be atomic in ().

Comment: The write operation will be atomic even though (
flock -s 200

# Put here your commands that must do some writes atomically

) 200>/var/lock/mylockfile  is sread across multiple concurrently running scripts? Or, conversely, is the lock only relative to /var/lock/mylockfile ?

Comment: Your script locks /var/lock/mylockfile, but only one instance of your script can get a write lock on it. Other instances will wait untill `/var/lock/mylockfile` is available for locking.

Comment: -s is a shared lock - suitable for reads, for a write lock you must use -x / -e. It is in the man page you linked.

Comment: At what point does the unlock occur in this code? As soon as something gets written to the `/var/lock/mylockfile` by the process that called `flock -x`?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski You can run this example `(flock -x 200; date; sleep 10; date;) 200>/var/lock/mylockfile` in two shells and see that unlocks happen only after all commands in () are executed (that is in a subshell)

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski To clarify @SergeiKurenkov 's answer: `flock` acquires the lock and the file handle holds it until the file is closed. In the example that's when the subshell exits. It doesn't have to be a subshell, a group command `{flock -x 200; dostuff; } 200> /the/lock/file` is good enough, the important thing is that the file is opened before `flock` and kept open until the lock is no longer needed.

Comment: Excellent job explaining what the 200 is for! (ok what is it for pls)

Answer (score 5):

`flock` is one of the ways of interlocking operations.  The utility is part of the util-linux toolset and is only available for Linux.  Other utilities, available across a wider range of platforms, are based around Daniel J. Bernstein's `setlock` utility from his daemontools package:

- [`setlock`](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/setlock.html) from daemontools
- [`setlock`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/setlock.8.html) from Bruce Guenter's daemontools-encore
- [`s6-setlock`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-setlock.html) from Laurent Bercot's s6
- [`chpst`](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html) from Gerrit Pape's runit
- [`runlock`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runlock.8) from Wayne Marshall's perp
- [`setlock`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/setlock.html) from my nosh toolset

These tools operate with a slightly different paradigm to that used in M. Kurenkov's answer (one that `flock` can also employ, but does not in that answer).  One invokes the `setlock` program to *chain load* to the command that must be interlocked.  `setlock` itself opens and locks the lock file, and leaves a file descriptor for it open in its process.  The lock persists for as long as that process does (unless the subsequent command chained to explicitly releases the lock by finding and closing the open file descriptor).

For the case in the question one must interlock the command that produces the output line, being aware that this invokes an *external* `echo` in place of a shell built-in `echo` command:

```
setlock mylockfile echo "$RESULT" >> ./$TEMP_DIR/$OUT_FILE
```

In this case it is not necessary to interlock opening the output file in append mode.  If it were, one would have to open that file within the lock, which necessitates either using programs like [`fdredir`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/fdredir.html)/[`redirfd`](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/redirfd.html):

```
setlock mylockfile fdredir --append 1 "./$TEMP_DIR/$OUT_FILE" echo "$RESULT"
```

which one can turn into a shell function if one wants:

```
outfile() { setlock mylockfile fdredir --append 1 "./$TEMP_DIR/$OUT_FILE" "$@" ; }
[…]
outfile echo "$RESULT"
```

or sticking with the shell syntax and having it interpreted by a second shell running under the interlock, requiring some non-trivial quoting if one's shell variables are not exported as environment variables:

```
setlock mylockfile sh -c 'echo '"$RESULT"' >> "./'$TEMP_DIR'/'$OUT_FILE'"'
```

This of course generalizes to things other than writing to output files:

```
setlock mylockfile sh -c '… interlocked ; stuff …'
```