# Using flock fails with zsh but works in bash?

Tags: zsh, flock

Employing the mechanism from the answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/274499/5132 in the Z shell:

```
(
flock -x 200

echo "test";

) 200>mylockfile2
```

returns

```
zsh: parse error near `200'
```

While in bash it works correctly. What may be the issue here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bash is the only shell that allows the user to open a fd higher than 9 directly using the normal redirection syntax. so in other shells the command is equivalent to `(...) 200 1>mylockfile2`, which is a syntax error. posix only mandates supporting 0-9. If you really want to ensure the fd used with the lock isn't already in use, you can use syntax specifically designed to open the next available fd. 
`(foo "$lockfd";...) {lockfd}>file`

Comment: What does `foo` or `lockfd` refer to? Is lockfd a special variable?

Comment: foo is a arbitrary command, lockfd is just a arbitrary variable named used to store the fd number opened by `{lockfd}`

Comment: `yash` also supports `200> file`. `rc`, `es`, `akanga` as well with the `>[200] file` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

`zsh` is not `bash` despite some efforts between the two camps of peeking over the fence and stealing ideas from one another. Also, `flock` appears to come from `util-linux` so portability may be limited. A ZSH solution might instead use the `zsystem` module; this module provides a `flock` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
zmodload zsh/system
(
   local lockvar
   touch lockfile
   zsystem flock -f lockvar lockfile
   print >&2 got lock
   sleep 10
   zsystem flock -u $lockvar
   print >&2 end lock
)
```

Comment: Why do you have the parentheses creating a sub shell? I could not think of a case where I would need them, the code seems to work just fine without the parentheses

Comment: @reportaman from the [docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html) "The lock terminates when the shell process that created the lock exits; it is therefore often convenient to create file locks within subshells, since the lock is automatically released when the subshell exits."