# Shell: mutual piping of STDIN/STDOUT of two commands

Tags: shell-script, pipe, io-redirection, ipc

When we run this with a POSIX shell,

```
$ cmd0 | cmd1
```

STDOUT of cmd0 is piped to STDIN of cmd1.

Q: On top of this, how can I **also** pipe STDOUT of cmd1 to STDIN of cmd0?

Is it mandatory to use redirect from/into a named pipe (FIFO) ? I don't like named pipes very much because they occupy some filesystem paths and I need to worry about name collisions. Or do I have to call pipe(2) via C, Python or some general purpose programming languages?

(Both cmd0 and cmd1 do some network I/O, so they won't block each other forever.)

Comment: Good to know some *nixes have "bidirectional pipes"... I wasn't imaginative enough to search across the archive with such a term.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On systems with bi-directional pipes (not Linux), you can do:

```
cmd0 <&1 | cmd1 >&0
```

On Linux, you can do:

```
: | { cmd1 | cmd2; } > /dev/fd/0
```

That works because on Linux (and Cygwin, but generally not other systems) `/dev/fd/x` where `x` is a fd to a pipe (named or not) acts like a named pipe, that is, opening it in read mode gets you the reading end and in write mode gets you the writing end.

With the [`yash` shell](https://osdn.jp/projects/yash/) and its `x>>|y` [*pipeline redirection* operator](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/yash.1.html#contenttoc8):

```
{ cmd0 | cmd1; } >>|0
```

With [shells with coproc support](/a/86372):

- zsh:

  ```
     coproc cmd0
     cmd1 <&p >&p
  ```
- ksh

  ```
     cmd0 |&
     cmd1 <&p >&p
  ```
- bash4+

  ```
     coproc cmd0
     cmd1 <&"${COPROC[0]}" >&"${COPROC[1]}"
  ```

Dedicated tool approaches (shamelessly copied from answers on [this very similar question](/q/53641)):

Using [`pipexec`](https://github.com/flonatel/pipexec)

```
pipexec [ A /path/to/cmd0 ] \
        [ B /path/to/cmd1 ] \
        '{A:1>B:0}' '{A:0>B:1}'
```

Or using [`dpipe`](http://wiki.v2.cs.unibo.it/wiki/index.php?title=VDE#dpipe)

```
dpipe cmd0 = cmd1
```

Or using [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/):

```
socat EXEC:cmd0 EXEC:cmd1,nofork                 # using socketpairs
socat EXEC:cmd0,commtype=pipes EXEC:cmd1,nofork  # using pipes
```

I don't know about `python`, but that's also relatively easily done in `perl`:

```
perl -e 'pipe STDOUT,STDIN; exec "cmd0 | cmd1"'
```

You can always also resort to named pipes, but finding unique names for them and some safe directory to create them in, restricting access to them (so other processes can't open them and interfere) and cleanup afterwards become additional problems which are hard to overcome reliably and portably.

In any case, beware of deadlocks!

Comment: Doesn't the `perl -e…` example buffers piped data by default?

Comment: @Kentzo, not sure what you mean, but in any case, `perl` is not involved at all in the flow of data there, it just creates the pipe and execs the shell which runs `cmd0 | cmd1` in the same process, so `perl` is gone by the time that shell starts, and the output of `cmd1` will be connected to the input of `cmd0` via that pipe created by `perl` earlier.

Comment: Perl buffers writes to `STDOUT` by defaults as far as I know. Thus data output by `cmd1`  may be retained by perl's internals until some threshold is reached before it's piped to `STDIN`.

Comment: @Kentzo, no again, `perl` doesn't read nor write anything here. It is gone (has been replaced by `sh`) by the time `cmd0` and `cmd1` are started. You can check with `perl -e 'pipe STDOUT,STDIN; exec "ps -f >&2"'` or `perl -e 'pipe STDOUT,STDIN; exec q((lsof -p "$$" +E -ad0,1 >&2); exit)'` to convince yourself.

Comment: You can simplify the Linux example to `: | { cmd1 | cmd2; } >/dev/fd/0`

Comment: @user414777. Thanks. That's much better indeed (also because in ksh/zsh, `cmd2` is still not run in a subshell). I've now edited in.