# How does bash coprocess achieve its pipelining?

Tags: bash, pipe, coprocesses

Note this passage from [man bash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bash.1.html) ( emphasis mine ):

> Coprocesses
>
> A coprocess is a shell command preceded by the coproc reserved word. A
>   coprocess is executed asynchronously in a subshell, as if the command
>   had been terminated with the & control operator, **with a two-way pipe**
>   established between the executing shell and the coprocess.

Now, as we know unlike other *nix systems, [Linux pipes are unidirectional](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53648/85039)(also ref [man pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), Portability section). So how does bash coproces achieve the "two-way pipe" without one existing on Linux ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It [makes one for stdin and one for stdout](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c?h=bash-5.0#n2384), the same way [pipes to subprocesses](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) always work. That's why [you get two fds in an array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Coprocesses). One end of each pipe is in the parent (as the FDs in the array), and one end of each pipe is in the child (as fd 0 and fd 1, stdin & stdout). Writing to fd 1 in the child gives you something to read from `COPROC[0]`, and vice-versa for standard input.

This setup is also described in the man page in the paragraph after the one you quoted. There's nothing special going on, and it [does the same thing](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/general.c?h=bash-5.0#n677) using the [standard `pipe` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html) on all systems, regardless of how the local pipes work over and above what POSIX provides.