# I need to forward from one server to another IP (Non HTTP) FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

This question has probably been asked before. Suppose I have FreeBSD 12, and I have a server with for example ip: `45.***.***.***` and I want it to forward a port like 25565 (Minecraft Server) to another ip: `95.***.***.***`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to forward a port from one machine to another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57721/how-to-forward-a-port-from-one-machine-to-another)

Comment: @JimL. No, without SSH. I want the VDS server to be a protection for the main server (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory I can use [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/)

Nginx can redirect tcp & udp traffic

Comment: would a proxy server like squid not work?

Comment: @fcbsd I think nginx can be http proxy

Answer (score 0):

A common usecase would be to setup a firewall which does the port redirection.

On FreeBSD there are three options, `pf`, `ipfw`, and `ipfilter`.

All are able to do this. Personally I think pf is the most easy to learn, but YMMV.
The handbook has some chapters on how to setup a firewall.