# Using netcat for port forwarding

Tags: linux, networking, netcat, nc

I have a process that listens on an `IP:port` - in fact it is spark streaming which connects to a socket. The issue is that I wish to somehow create a server that connects to spark on one port and data is streamed into this server from another port.

For example, the spark streaming example uses the netcat utility (for example `nc -lk 5005`). However, I have another service that listens for incoming messages and then spit out a message. So I need some kind of server that can listen to messages from service A and pass them to spark.

My service A, relies on sockets. And my spark consumer relies on sockets.

Here is what I have done so far is the forwarding from port to port but this does not seem to work:

```
nc -X 4 -x 127.0.0.1:5005 localhost 5006
```

With the idea that the service `A:5005` -> socket -> `5006` -> Spark

I cannot seem to find the correct way to make this work.

Some answers have suggested the following:

```
socat tcp-l:5005,fork,reuseaddr tcp:127.0.0.1:5006
```

My spark socket reciever doesn't or cannot seem to connect. I get the error: `Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:5006 - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: are you sure port 5006 is open?! ; whatis ouput this command sudo netstat -nltp

Answer (score 80):

you can't use only `nc` for forward traffic, `nc`  have not `keep-alive` or `fork` mode

you must use another tools instead `nc`; for example use `socat` or `ncat`

---

- [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) ([source code](https://repo.or.cz/socat.git))

this command listen on port `5050` and forward all to port `2020`

```
socat tcp-l:5050,fork,reuseaddr tcp:127.0.0.1:2020
```

- `ncat` [readmore](https://nmap.org/ncat/)

> Ncat is a feature-packed networking utility which reads and writes
>   data across networks from the command line. Ncat was written for the
>   Nmap Project as a much-improved reimplementation of the venerable
>   Netcat. It

```
ncat -l localhost 8080 --sh-exec "ncat example.org 80"
```

And you can use another tools:

- [goproxy](https://github.com/snail007/goproxy): (download [source code or bin file](https://github.com/snail007/goproxy/releases))

Listen on port 1234 and forward it to port 4567 on address "1.1.1.1"

```
./proxy tcp -p ":1234" -T tcp -P "1.1.1.1:4567"
```

- [gost](https://github.com/ginuerzh/gost) (Download [source code](https://github.com/ginuerzh/gost/releases) [and bin](https://github.com/ginuerzh/gost/releases)) [ENGLISH readme](https://github.com/ginuerzh/gost/blob/master/README_en.md)

Listen on port 1234 and forward it to port 4567 on address "1.1.1.1" [source](https://docs.ginuerzh.xyz/gost/en/port-forwarding/)

```
./gost -L tcp://:1234/1.1.1.1:4567
```

- [redir](https://github.com/troglobit/redir) ([source code](https://github.com/troglobit/redir))

  `./redir :1234 1.1.1.1:5678`

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first socat test, but the issue is that my streaming instance expects something there all the time and is listening at 5006 - without this, I get an error.

Comment: ncap also has options for proxies... Which allows for some interesting things... (`gost` looks awesome though....)

Comment: +1 for goproxy! Just amazing...

Comment: The `ncat` command consistently fails after the first http connection. So typically getting the `index.html`, but failing on the later requests.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar use case. Mine was to listen to an external port and forward it to an internal port which pointed at a reverse ssh tunnel.

External port: 8001

Internal port: 18820

```
nc -l -k -p 8001 -c "nc 127.0.0.1 18820"
```

REF:

[Simple way to create a tunnel from one local port to another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/simple-way-to-create-a-tunnel-from-one-local-port-to-another/101906#101906)

[How can i keep netcat connection open?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423407/how-can-i-keep-netcat-connection-open)

Comment: ubuntu needs package ncat for the -c, the nc package doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2):

For port forwarding only by net cat you can use pipes:

```
mkfifo pip
nc -l -p port_to_listen < pip | nc target_ip port_to_be_forwarded > pip
```

Or:

```
nc target_ip port_to_be_forwarded < pip | nc -l -p port_to_listen > pip
```

Comment: Are each of these pipes uni-directional and would you need both to have a duplex channel?