# How can I keep netcat connection open?

Tags: shell-script, netcat, dialog

I have two files, `client.sh` and `server.sh`. All the necessary data is on the server, which is sent to the client using **netcat**. The client just get these data and display it to the end user. The problem is, when I try to show the dialog loading screen from the server to the client:

### server.sh

```
# CLIENT PORT: 8765
# SERVER PORT: 5678

while :
do
    touch registered_users data

    nc -vv -l -p 5678 > data

    case `cat data` in
        "SPLASH_SCREEN")
            for ((i=0;i<100;i++))
            do
                echo $i
            done | dialog --title 'Loading...' --gauge 'Welcome!' 8 40 0 > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/8765
        ;;
    esac
done
```

### client.sh

```
# CLIENT PORT: 8765
# SERVER PORT: 5678

echo "SPLASH_SCREEN" > /dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/5678

while :
do
    nc -l -p 8765 > server_response
    cat server_response
done
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Solved it! just had to use the -k option

```
 -k    Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current
       connection is completed.  It is an error to use this option without the
       -l option.
```

> **EDIT:** This answer assumes you're using `openbsd-netcat`, some versions like `gnu-netcat` have a reduced set of features, hence some flags like `-k` might not be present, package names might vary according to your distro

Comment: so final command is ` nc -vv -k -l -p 5678`

Comment: Is this `-k` option standard? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: @smac89 depends on the netcat version you're using, on the man pages i found, all of them had the `-k` option, remember that some things might differ between the BSD netcat and the GNU one