# bash read netcat status in pipe then exit

Tags: bash, netcat

I don't understand how to properly setup a data transmission between two host with unstable ethernet connection.

This is my `/simple/bash/script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash


while [ true ]; do
    cat /dev/virtual  | nc -v 192.168.1.1 5005 || echo "nc failed" && exit   
    sleep 5s
done

exit
```

If I manually start it and on the destination `netcat` isn't running it would say:

```
5005 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

But it would not exit.

I need it the other way:

1. check `netcat` connection is ok.
2. then pipe `cat /dev/virtual`.

Is there a way to catch the `netcat` status and then if it is `failed: connection refused` restart the main bash script?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to understand but I'm not able to. What you want to do is "until netcat doesn't accept the connection, wait. When nc is okay, send `/dev/virtual` via netcat"?

Comment: Yes Francesco, you've explained it better than me. That is what I would like to do.

Comment: Why restart the script if the only code is in a loop anyway?

Comment: That is called "useless use of cat". Do this instead: `nc -v 192.168.1.1 5005 </dev/virtual`

Comment: I was thinking to migrate the script to a systemd unit. That's why I would like to restart entire script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! nc -z 192.168.1.1 5005 ; then
    sleep 1 && "$0" & exit;
fi

nc -v 192.168.56.203 5005 < /dev/virtual
```

Explanation:

- `nc -z` will check if someone is listening on the other side
- if no one is listening, the program will sleep for 1 sec (obviously you can change this) and then it will start another instance of itself and exit
- if someone is listening, then the program will send `/dev/virtual`

Comment: Thank you,  I've tried with:
 if ! nc -z $IPADDRESS 5005 ; then         echo  "Not avilable" && sleep 1 && "$0" ;     fi
But connection on the other side get closed after the execution: "
nc -i 1 -l -v -p 5005
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 5005)
Connection from 10.11.10.11 33908 received!"

Comment: @user340971 if you're not running on Debian, you can use the `-k` option of netcat. Check those answers: [how-can-i-keep-netcat-connection-open](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423407/how-can-i-keep-netcat-connection-open), [nc-exits-immediately-on-connection](https://serverfault.com/questions/754705/nc-exits-immediately-on-connection-when-run-as-an-upstart-job). If you're running on Debian, check this answer: [netcat-keep-listening-for-connection-in-debian](https://superuser.com/questions/1008348/netcat-keep-listening-for-connection-in-debian)