# Ip forwarding between two linux server

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I have two linux server to run a vpn server, one from Germany and other in Iran, but in Iran because of some policy for hard filtering after two or something like that in hour my Germany ip is filtered. How can i forwarding ip to my Germany server without leaking information or anyway for securely to do that?

I do some basic ip forwarding and cause this problem...

Comment: As the question is probably to very Linux&UNIX specific, you could try to ask in https://serverfault.com/ instead.

Comment: Since VPNs typically encrypt the network traffic passing through the VPN, anyone in Iran monitoring your network traffic won't be able to read its contents if the encryption is good. But **they will still be able to see that an encrypted connection exists** between your server and another server in Germany. Hiding the **existence** of that encrypted stream is a much harder problem than just encrypting the **contents** of the VPN traffic stream.

Comment: ip forwarding is a bit difficult, instead use tcp port forwarding https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293304/using-netcat-for-port-forwarding/293308#293308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few aspects to your question.

We can only guess what 'the Iranian firewall' is doing.
Or when it will block connections, I've seen similar problems with the the Chinese state firewall, sometimes my VPN tunnel would work for weeks before I had to switch network ports. Pure guess work really.

I would start by simply creating an IPSEC tunnel between your Iran server and your Germany server and route all traffic from the Iran server through the Germany server. This way all traffic is encrypted until it reaches Germany.
You could also do this with NetGuard which might be easier to setup.
Another option that comes to mind is routing traffic through an SSH connection from A to B.

Hope this helps.