# Local port forwarding on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding, port, socat

I have a service listening on port `:3000`. However, I would like to change that to port `:8080`. Unfortunately, the program that I'm running does not allow me to change the listen port.

Is there any way that I could have `localhost` forward port `:3000` to port `:8080`? So when I connect externally on `:8080` it will forward that traffic to `:3000`?

I tried the `socat` commnand, but it didn't seem to work.

Edit: I tried the following command (found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/simple-way-to-create-a-tunnel-from-one-local-port-to-another)). It didn't display anything, but the command kept running. When I tried to open it in Firefox, it just kept loading forever, eventually getting the connection timed out error. In chrome it said that the connection was reset. I apologize if this was me not configuring the command properly, I'm not familiar with `socat` or networking.

`socat tcp-listen:8080,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:3000`

Edit 2: I ran `nmap` on localhost (`ssh`ing into the device), scanning for all ports. For some reason, it didn't show port `:3000` as open. However, when I used its public IP address rather than localhost, port `:3000` showed up. I'm hosting through Linode, if anybody knows why this is happening.

Edit 3: So the port is apparently forwarding properly, because when I use the `curl` command (using the public IP), it gives me the correct HTML code and an `HTTP 200 OK` status. But when I try to open it in a browser, I get `connection timed out` (Firefox) or `connection was reset` (Chrome). So it seems to be a browser issue. I know I'm trying to connect via `HTTPS` on port 8080, if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `socat` should be able to do this.  Can you edit your answer to include details about what you tried with `socat` and how it failed?

Comment: @satwell I edited my post to include the details of my experience with the `socat` command.

Comment: The `socat` command you're trying should work.  A connection refused error from `socat` indicates that it can't actually connect to `localhost` on port `3000`.  So either you don't have anything listening on `localhost` port `3000`, or `localhost` is not resolving the way you expect.  Including an example error from `socat` would help.  Also the output of `netstat -ln | grep :3000` will help diagnose whether there's anything listening for connections on port `3000` and at what addresses.

Comment: Is it possible that a firewall is blocking this port?

Comment: @satwell My apologies, I had accidentally switched `3000`'s and `8080`'s place in the command. I put them in their proper places, and it just doesn't output anything, but the command continues to run. As for @mnme's post, I am sure there is no firewall blocking the port. I ran a test with node.js, and I could access that just fine.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, socat is now running without printing errors, but Firefox is behaving as though the URL is unreachable, right?  The next step would be to try curl instead of Firefox:  `curl -v http://<ip>:8080`.  Using curl will provide clearer debugging information than Firefox.

Comment: @satwell The `curl` command worked just fine. I got an `HTTP 200 OK` response and the correct HTML code. But when I open it in Firefox, it loads for several minutes before telling me that the connection timed out.